# RDLC Design Page Can't Connect to context.cs in EF6 vs. EF Core (Different .NET Versions)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, reportviewer

I'm using C# .NET 6

I opened two separate projects for this problem:

One using .Net Framework 4.8 The other using .Net 6 I tried separately in both projects:

In the project using .Net Framework 4.8, I installed Entity Framework 6 (EF6) and was able to establish connections to the objects in context.cs from the report.rdlc design page.

In the project using .Net 6, I installed EfCore, but I cannot establish connections to context.cs from the report.rdlc design page.

Comment: Did you create an EF Core DbContext for the .Net Core projects to reference? EF Core referenced classes won't be able to use an EF6 (.Net Framework) DbContext.

Comment: DbContext is the DbContext of EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext @StevePy